# android: data binding error: cannot find symbol class

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am getting started for using `DataBinding` feature. I am facing problem with it.

> Error:(21, 9) error: cannot find symbol class
>   ContactListActivityBinding

**build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.letsnurture.ln_202.databindingdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

**ContactListActivity.java**

```
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.letsnurture.ln_202.databindingdemo.model.Contact;

public class ContactListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ContactListActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_contact_list);
        Contact user = new Contact("Chintan Soni", "+91 9876543210");
        binding.setContact(user);

//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contact_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**content_contact_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.letsnurture.ln_202.databindingdemo.ContactListActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_contact_list">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.letsnurture.ln_202.databindingdemo.model.Contact" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.contactName}"
            tools:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.contactNumber}"
            tools:text="Number" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**activity_contact_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.letsnurture.ln_202.databindingdemo.ContactListActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_contact_list" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can u post ur manifest contents here? because your class is ContactListActivity but error says ContactListActivityBinding so you might be typing wrong name in manifest file's activity tag check out!

Comment: your class should be named ActivityContactListBinding

Comment: make sure that `kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1'` has the same version as for gradle, `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'`

Comment: In my case it was just confusing error reporting. The reported error was that the symbol for the Binding was not found. This was true, but the underlying problem was that there I had done my binding incorrectly, so it was not being generated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is your code

```
ContactListActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_contact_list);
```

Replace this code

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_contact_list);
```

Comment: This is not looking like the correct answer. I would expect the following: `ActivityContactListBinding binding =  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_contact_list);` Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you give some description on this, so that we can learn from this. BTW it works like charm!

Comment: This can not be right, as Binding class is generated similar to name of layout.

Comment: How's that even possible? What if I don't have a class with ActivityMain?

Answer (score 56):

I consistently run into this problem. I believe it has to do with android studio not being aware of dynamically generated files. If you have everything else right for databinding try to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...  and select Invalidate Caches and Restart. Then try and import the BR file... it should import fine.

You may have to throw in a Clean and Rebuild.

Comment: I tried cleaning multiple times but `Invalidate Caches/Restart` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: When I get this problem even Invalidate Caches, Clean and Rebuild are not helping. This is crazy. The only working solution for me is renaming the layout file or creating a clean repository clone.

Answer (score 38):

You can see **[Main Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579759/6891563)** for complete information about data binding errors and solutions. I will try to tell some important points below.

#### 5 Tips that I use to solve binding issues.

Assuming that you have **[enabled data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start)** in `build.gradle` and you have converted your layout to **[binding layout](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions)**.

First of all binding class auto generate when you convert layout to binding layout. Still sometimes it is not generated when background threads are not working. Here are some tips for you to resolve this.

> **(1) Name of generated class**

Layout name is in **snake_case** `activity_main.xml`

Data binding class will be in **PascalCase** like `ActivityMainBinding`.

> **(2). Type full name of Binding class**

I felt sometimes when you type **`ActivityMai...`**, then it **does not show suggestion**, but that **does not mean** class is **not generated**. In that case you should **type full name** of expected generated class. Like type `ActivityMainBinding` and it **will show import popup**. (That's what i faced many times.)

Still not getting import suggestion. Try manual import.

```
import <yourpackage>databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
```

> **(3). Rebuild Project**

If still your class is not generated. **(Some time when we paste layout file, then it happens)**. Then **Rebuild Project** from `Build> Rebuild` (*Not Build or Make project*). It will generate your data binding class. (**Rebuild does Magic for me all times.**)

**(4)** If you have created an **`<variable`** in your layout and it **does not show up its setter and getter** in data binding class, then **follow 4th point**.

**(5)** Still if your class is not generating then you should **check if build is not failing due to an error** in your layout file. Data binding class will generate with a successful build.

This is all what i do to solve my data binding errors. If you get any further issue, you can comment here.

#### [Source answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579759/6891563)

Comment: Point 5 is a good one - but it's often the case that when a build fails because of databinding, the error presented is vague, and sometimes has nothing to do with the actual problem. Running `./gradlew :app:build --stacktrace` will provide much more useful information

Comment: Point 5 did work for me too. For me, I missed a parameter in a function call done with `onclick` attribute in layout. It did not give any error on the editor.

Comment: Yep, number 5 did the trick

Answer (score 27):

This problem may be occur when there is problem in layout file. 
In my case I just use wrong way to call method

```
android:onClick="@={() -> viewModel.showText()}"
```

instead of

```
  android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.showText()}"
```

Answer (score 24):

Please refer to the [android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#binding_data)

> Layout file was main_activity.xml so the generate class was MainActivityBinding

Since your xml is named "activity_contact_list.xml", you should use **ActivityContactListBinding** instead of the original one

Comment: This one is really important!

Answer (score 17):

Actually it can be happend for various reason and for poor logging mechanism in data binding it is very hard to find the reason.So go got the proper error first go to the terminal and run the following command-

```
gradlew :app:build --stacktrace
```

It will show you the proper error with the number of line in XML where error is found.

**For example -**

```
ERROR: Could not find accessor com.example.model file://app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_example.xml Line:91
```

Answer (score 11):

Improper package names can also cause the above error. As of Android Gradle plugin 3.2 (as far as I can tell) CamelCase package names will be inferred improperly as `classes`, which will break the generated binding object.

Example:

```
src
|
-> FooPackage
    |
    -> Bar.java
```

will be generated wrongly as

```
import src.FooPackage

...

public abstract class MyBinding extends ViewDataBinding {
    @NonNull
    public final FooPackage.Bar mInstance;
...
}
```

This obviously doesn't make any sense.

Refactor `FooPackage` to `foopackage` according to [java conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) and be saved. You will then get:

```
import src.foopackage.Bar

...

public abstract class MyBinding extends ViewDataBinding {
    @NonNull
    public final Bar mInstance;
...
}
```

Comment: Your awesome and your solution really worked for me. My mistake was I made my folder name in capital letters like Company.CompanyViewModel. Then I refactor it into company.CompanyViewModel and then it compiled well.

Comment: I know this is old but worked like a charm! databinding is very sensible with names. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

You need to check your layout file, this error occurs due to the wrong use of data binding expression i.e you may not using proper syntax

Answer (score 6):

I was calling my `onClick` wrong, which caused this error. So I changed

```
android:onClick="@{listener.onDogClicked()}"
```

to

```
android:onClick="@{listener::onDogClicked}"
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare and pass the binding in the activity layout, not in the included layout.

Example from [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#includes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <data>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <include layout="@layout/name"
           bind:user="@{user}"/>
       <include layout="@layout/contact"
           bind:user="@{user}"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

> Here, there must be a user variable in both the name.xml and contact.xml layout files.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the name for your model and the reference have the same name:

For example, name=**"item"** must match android:checked="@={**item**.checked}"

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="item"
        type="com.simone.mywordlist.model.MyModel" />
</data>

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/my_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="@={item.checked}"
            />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Stupid and insignificant errors are always the hardest to find.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to add in app level gradle, `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Comment: Add this to both both the base module (app) and the module that contains your view, if your view is in another module.

Comment: Thankssss Buddy you saved my hours:)

Answer (score 3):

If you have changed your object package location and you forgot to update it import info into xml, that error can be occurred. Please check your object package location and its xml import package location.

Answer (score 2):

You must change your `activity_contact_list` to be binded - add layout tag as you did in `content_contact_list`. Don't forget, The root layout inside `activity_contact_list` must have an id for the Binding class to be generated and will be named **ActivityContactListBinding** (i.e. the name of the layout with camel casting instead of underscores).

Next, inside `activity_contact_list`, give `<include layout="@layout/content_contact_list" />` an id, then you will have access for its binding instance through your ActivityContactListBinding instance.

Somthing like:

```
binding.contentContactList.setContact(user);
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same error, but with Kotlin usage.

To resolve it, i make some changes in gradles files :

In **project**'s Gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.40"
}
```

In **app**'s Gradle file :

```
dependencies {

    ...
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.30"
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2'
}


kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

//used to resolve annotation conflicts
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the reason of these errors are not the `DataBinding` itself, but some other part of our code. In my case I had an error in `Room` database so the compiler couldn't generate the binding classes and it gives me these errors.

According to **Google**:

> Previous versions of the data binding compiler generated the binding classes in the same step that compiles your managed code. If your managed code fails to compile, you might get multiple errors reporting that the binding classes aren't found. The new data binding compiler prevents these errors by generating the binding classes before the managed compiler builds your app.

So to enable new data binding compiler, add the following option to your **gradle.properties** file:

```
android.databinding.enableV2=true
```

You can also enable the new compiler in your gradle command by adding the following parameter:

```
-Pandroid.databinding.enableV2=true
```

**Note** that the new compiler in Android Studio version **3.2** is **enabled by default**.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had the same issue but the reason was different. My onClick function was declared private in the activity class, so be sure that, if you are using a handler function inside the layout, **the function must not be private**.

```
// this will not be visible in the binded layout because it's private!
private fun mainButtonClick(view: View) {
    if (viewModel.isRecording.value == true) {
        stopRecordingAndPlaying()
    } else {
        startRecordingAndPlaying()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yah, I have the same problem and it's because my property is private. +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same issue and I found that variable name and method were missing. Double check the layout file or look for build error that says DATABINDINGISSUE, or invalidate and restart android studio. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

In my project it was a trouble in:

```
android:text="@{safeUnbox(viewmodel.population)}"
```

So I've wrapped it in `String.valueOf()` :

```
android:text="@{String.valueOf(safeUnbox(viewmodel.population))}"
```

And it was resolved

Answer (score 2):

For me it was an error in the layout xml binding, I had

app:setNameString="@{person}"

instead of

app:nameString="@{person}"

the type name must match the name you have set up in the @BindingAdapter class (if you are using binding adapter)

Answer (score 2):

make all your packages name's in the project that you used in binding to lower case.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same issue
when i try this without viewBinding

```
  buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
```

this will give that error while enabling view binding everything to work properly

```
  buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }
```

Comment: I found dataBinding was added automatically when trying to initiate Google Maps. Took ages to find this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I fell into this issue because my Activity was called MainActivityMVVM and the Binding was converted into `MainActivityMvvmBinding` instead of `MainActivityMVVMBinding`. After digging into the generated classes I found the issue.

Answer (score 1):

### Keypoint

Your layout name is in **snake_case**.

```
activity_login.xml
```

Then your binding class name will be in **CamelCase**.

```
ActivityLoginBinding.java
```

**Also build project after creating layout. Sometimes it is not generated automatically.**

Answer (score 1):

Just remove "build" folder in youy project directory and compile again, i hope it works for you too

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the  tags into your Activity's Xml Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
             name=""
             type="" />
    </data
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context="com.letsnurture.ln_202.databindingdemo.ContactListActivity">

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

and then, add an android:id into your  tag

After that, you'll have a ActivityContactListBinding object and you can access and bind variables on your included layouts.

Answer (score 1):

After ensuring the naming conventions are correct as described in other answers, and also trying to invalidate the cache and restart, deleting temp/cache folders the issue still persisted for me.

I got rid of it as follows:
Add a new dummy XML resource. This will trigger bindings and its meta-data to re-create across the project. The annoying compile errors should no longer be visible anymore. You now delete the dummy XML you added.

For me as of August 2020, the Binding would automatically get corrupted repeatedly. It seems to be biting more than it can chew under the hood.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue repeatedly. I have used temporary solution by just make some change in XML file and error goes automatically and I have undone that change. 
Really this issue is so irritating while working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a package with the same name as a missing import in the generated databinding class.. It seems like the compiler got confused.

Answer (score 0):

your model just have **getter and setter** in ***androidX.***
else not find your model in view and show this bug

```
public class User {

String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public User(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might actually be on this line:

```
<include layout="@layout/content_contact_list" />
```

Android Studio gets a little confused at time and takes the `include layout` for the `layout` tag. What's even more frustrating is that this could work the first time, fails to work with a modification on the Java/Kotlin code later, and then work again after a tweak that forces it to rebuild the binding. You may want to replace `<include>` tags with something that populates it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was putting `onClick` function to call asynchronous/`suspend` function which gave me an error `cannot find a symbol class ... impl`.

**.xml file**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="dataFragment"
            type="com.example.todoapp.fragment.SubmissionFragment" />
    </data>
    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/keepBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="@{() -> dataFragment.submit()}"
        android:text="Add" />
</layout>
```

**.fragment file**

```
private lateinit val stringList: List<String>

...

suspend fun submit() {
        dataDao.insert(stringList)
        val action = SubmissionFragmentDirections.actionSubmissionFragmentToTodoFragment()
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
```

Then I replace `Async Method` with `Launch Method` by removing suspend function and insert `viewModelScope.launch`

```
fun submit() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
       dataDao.insert(stringList)
    }

    val action = SubmissionFragmentDirections.actionSubmissionFragmentToTodoFragment()
    findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
```

reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/launch-vs-async-in-kotlin-coroutines/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use the Same id in Layout widgets