# Databinding error in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-databinding

My project was now building up good. Suddenly it started showing error in all DataBinding generated files. I cant find a way to get through it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49810207/7666442

Comment: Sorry, it doest suit the answer.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Cannot find databinding file

Answer (score 0):

just invalidate cache and restart android studio, if still it don't work just try deleting build and .gradle folder.

Comment: Then try deleting build and .gradle folder

Comment: I dint get you.

Answer (score 0):

Databinding removes all boilerplate codes, but it's hard to debug. If you get any sort of databinding error, kindly check the build error message properly. The errors are pointed out in the build message.

Note: If any of the databinding code has an error, you will get error for all databinding codes. So, it gets quite tough to get which file has the actual issue. The issue occurs mainly if you refractor any view id. Have a close look at at which places, you ids are getting changed.