# Android DataBinding : Unable to access LayoutNameDataBinding even if it is generated

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

My problem is that I need to access my LayoutNameBinding, but I am unable to do so. Only DataBinding generated class which is available is LayoutNameBindingImpl.

- Build is successful (No errors)
- DataBinding is enabled within build.gradle(:app)
- DataBinding plugin kotlin-apt is applied within build.gradle(:app)
- My layout is contained within a `<layout>`
- LobbyFragmentBinding.java is generated and contains LobbyFragmentBinding

The commented part is what I would like to be able to do within my code. 
Part of the code shown is inspired of https://github.com/android/sunflower which explains how to use different parts of Android JetPack.

### Solutions tried

- Rebuild
- Manually add "import com.kotlin.projet3.databinding.LobbyFragmentBinding"
- Solutions found at [android: data binding error: cannot find symbol class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126670/android-data-binding-error-cannot-find-symbol-class) (Problem is not the same, but tried anyways)
- Solutions found at [Data Binding class not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483094/data-binding-class-not-generated) (Problem is not the same, but tried anyways)

[Intellisense Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgVwD.png)

### LobbyFragment.kt

```
package com.kotlin.projet3.ui.lobby

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.kotlin.projet3.R
import com.kotlin.projet3.adapters.GAME_LIST_INDEX
import com.kotlin.projet3.adapters.MATCH_HISTORY_INDEX
import com.kotlin.projet3.adapters.PROFILE_INDEX
import com.kotlin.projet3.databinding.LobbyFragmentBindingImpl

class LobbyFragment : Fragment(){
    private lateinit var nav: NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

//        val binding = LobbyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
//
//        viewPager = binding.viewPager
//        viewPager.adapter = LobbyTabsAdapter(this)
//
//        TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabs, viewPager) { tab, position ->
//            tab.setIcon(getTabIcon(position))
//            tab.text = getTabTitle(position)
//        }.attach()
//
//        return binding.root
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun getTabIcon(position: Int): Int {
        return when (position) {
            GAME_LIST_INDEX -> R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp
            PROFILE_INDEX -> R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp
            MATCH_HISTORY_INDEX -> R.drawable.ic_assessment_black_24dp
            else -> throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()
        }
    }

    private fun getTabTitle(position: Int): String? {
        return when (position) {
            GAME_LIST_INDEX -> getString(R.string.home_button)
            PROFILE_INDEX -> getString(R.string.profile_button)
            MATCH_HISTORY_INDEX -> getString(R.string.match_history_button)
            else -> null
        }
    }
}
```

### lobby_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/page_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"


            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view_pager"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".15"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true" />

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabs"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### LobbyFragmentBinding.java (Generated file)

```
// Generated by data binding compiler. Do not edit!
package com.kotlin.projet3.databinding;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.kotlin.projet3.R;
import java.lang.Deprecated;
import java.lang.Object;

public abstract class LobbyFragmentBinding extends ViewDataBinding {
  @NonNull
  public final ConstraintLayout pageContainer;

  @NonNull
  public final TabLayout tabs;

  @NonNull
  public final ViewPager2 viewPager;

  protected LobbyFragmentBinding(Object _bindingComponent, View _root, int _localFieldCount,
      ConstraintLayout pageContainer, TabLayout tabs, ViewPager2 viewPager) {
    super(_bindingComponent, _root, _localFieldCount);
    this.pageContainer = pageContainer;
    this.tabs = tabs;
    this.viewPager = viewPager;
  }

  @NonNull
  public static LobbyFragmentBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot) {
    return inflate(inflater, root, attachToRoot, DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent());
  }

  /**
   * This method receives DataBindingComponent instance as type Object instead of
   * type DataBindingComponent to avoid causing too many compilation errors if
   * compilation fails for another reason.
   * https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116541301
   * @Deprecated Use DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.lobby_fragment, root, attachToRoot, component)
   */
  @NonNull
  @Deprecated
  public static LobbyFragmentBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot, @Nullable Object component) {
    return ViewDataBinding.<LobbyFragmentBinding>inflateInternal(inflater, R.layout.lobby_fragment, root, attachToRoot, component);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static LobbyFragmentBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return inflate(inflater, DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent());
  }

  /**
   * This method receives DataBindingComponent instance as type Object instead of
   * type DataBindingComponent to avoid causing too many compilation errors if
   * compilation fails for another reason.
   * https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116541301
   * @Deprecated Use DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.lobby_fragment, null, false, component)
   */
  @NonNull
  @Deprecated
  public static LobbyFragmentBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable Object component) {
    return ViewDataBinding.<LobbyFragmentBinding>inflateInternal(inflater, R.layout.lobby_fragment, null, false, component);
  }

  public static LobbyFragmentBinding bind(@NonNull View view) {
    return bind(view, DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent());
  }

  /**
   * This method receives DataBindingComponent instance as type Object instead of
   * type DataBindingComponent to avoid causing too many compilation errors if
   * compilation fails for another reason.
   * https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116541301
   * @Deprecated Use DataBindingUtil.bind(view, component)
   */
  @Deprecated
  public static LobbyFragmentBinding bind(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Object component) {
    return (LobbyFragmentBinding)bind(component, view, R.layout.lobby_fragment);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which line provides the error if you uncomment the commented section you wish to work?

Comment: val binding = LobbyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false) 
throws a compilation error because it is unable to resolve LobbyFragmentBinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bug Tracker** https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151140024

### Workaround used (a simpler one probably exists, investigation to pinpoint bug was done afterward)

1. Copy content of lobby_fragment and LobbyFragment
2. Delete lobby_fragment and LobbyFragment
3. Create LobbyFragment and lobby_fragment
4. Paste copied content

After investigation, the problem seems linked to the way layout files are arranged within my project. I defined extra ressource source dirs within my build.gradle(:app) and when I move my layout files to those folders before doing the first build which would create the generated DataBinding files, the issue within this thread appears.

### build.gradle(:app)

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res {
                srcDirs 'src/main/res', 
                'src/main/res/layouts/chat',
                'src/main/res/layouts/authentication', 
                'src/main/res/layouts/lobby'
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```